# Looking a more terse syntax for repeating columns of a pattern using css grid?

Tags: html, css, syntax, css-grid

Is there any syntax for repeating this exact grid layout?

```
.grid-system {    
  grid-template-columns: 42px 48px 42px 48px 42px 48px 42px 48px 42px 48px 42px;
}
```

I tried but it seemingly didn't work:

```
.grid-system {    
  grid-template-columns: repeat(11, 42px, 48px);
}
```

Here's a code pen with more details:

https://codepen.io/matthewharwood/pen/vPXWmm

As you can see the design breaks the default grid system so I made a flattened grid (`samba-flat-grid`) w/o gaps to compensate:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `grid-template-columns: repeat(11, 42px 48px)` - without the *space* between them. Check [`here`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat) for all the possibilities.

See demo below:

```css
.samba-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 42px);
  background: pink;
  width: 100%;
  column-gap: 48px;
}

.samba-flat-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(11, 42px 48px); /* CHANGED */
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1032px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: green;
}

.section {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: papayawhip;
}

.element-1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: span 6;
}

.element-2 {
  grid-column-start: 7;
  grid-column-end: span 6;
}

.element-inner-img {
  background: blue;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: span 6;
}

.element-inner-img img {
  width: 100%;
}

.element-inner-content {
  background: #b000b5;
  grid-column-start: 7;
  grid-column-end: 12;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="samba-grid">
      <div class="element-1">
        <div class="samba-flat-grid">
          <div class="element-inner-img">
            <img src="https://placebear.com/1600/900" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="element-inner-content">
            <p>Hello World</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="element-2">

        <div class="samba-flat-grid">
          <div class="element-inner-img">
            <img src="https://placebear.com/1600/900" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="element-inner-content">
            <p>Hello World</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doh just a typo!  Hey theres no way to keep the original grid and make an element inside span over a gutter right?  (will mark this correct regardless asap)

Comment: grid items span over gutter only when they span over the next item too; so the answer is no